# Why would a call to a web service method time out almost immediately?

Tags: web-services, .net-4.0, windows-server-2003

The production version of this web service using .NET 1.1 does not have this problem.  This is on a test environment running .NET 4.0 on Windows Server 2003.

I have a problem where I am receiving the following exception:

```
    System.Net.WebException: The operation has timed out    
at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetRequestStream(TransportContext& context)    
at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetRequestStream()    
at System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapHttpClientProtocol.Invoke(String methodName, Object[] parameters)    
at HTP.RHIO.PIRManager.TargetWS.PIRService.Upload(Transmission t_request)    
at HTP.RHIO.PIRManager.Manager.PIRManager.Upload(Transmission request)
```

This occurs when my webservice's Upload method calls another webservice's Upload method.  The timeout occurs almost immediately, about 1/3 of a second (note the log_datetime column)

[image: Log]

Code:  (The line where it logs the interval in the exception output is not yet implemented, that's why it doesn't appear in the output.  It should be falling through to the default value of interval = 60 [*1000])

```
int interval = 0;                                                                           
try 
{

    try
    {
        interval = Convert.ToInt16(System.Configuration.ConfigurationSettings.AppSettings["RealTimeTimeOutSeconds"]);
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        interval = 60;
    }

    interval = interval * 1000;
    target.Timeout = interval;
    trans = target.Upload(trans);
    }                               
    catch(System.Net.WebException ex)
    {               
        request.TransmissionHeader.MessageCode = GetReturnMessageCode(ex); 
        request.TransmissionHeader.Message = ex.Message;
        Log(request.TransmissionHeader, "Upload", "FAILED", "(Timeout = " + interval.ToString() + ") " + ex.ToString(), 1);

        trans = TA1forFailedRealtimeUpload(trans.TransmissionHeader);                                       
        request = ConvertToLocal(trans, request);
        Log(request.TransmissionHeader, "Upload", "SENDING", "Responding to sender with TA1", 1);
        return request;                             
    }
}
```

and from my web service's web.config file:

```
<httpRuntime executionTimeout="600" maxRequestLength="2000000"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

`Convert.ToInt16` may not do quite what you're expecting. From [the manual](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/basyfs27.aspx);

> Return Value
>
> Type: System.Int16
> A 16-bit signed integer that is equivalent to the number in value, **or 0 (zero) if value is null.**

If `RealTimeTimeOutSeconds` is not set in your configuration, you'll be converting NULL, which will result in a zero timeout.